# why css not apply on span tag and background image not display?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I make a header as shown in image. I face two issues while making the header. I am not able to add ellipsis to `span` tag. I used one `span` tag. I want to add ellipsis when screen resolution is small. I do like that. I want to add ellipsis on this element .

```
<div class='sign-out'>
    <span>Show  name</span>
    <a>Sign out</a>
</div>
```

```css
.sign-out span {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 10%;
}
```

I want to add image as shown in uploaded pic. It is not displayed appropriately as it is demo image.

```
<div class='toggle-icon'>
    <span class='image-background'>
        <img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gisoddbkajwuk1j/chart.png?dl=0'/>
    </span>
    <span class='image-background'>
        <img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6yft5r97hi1pik7/table.png?dl=0'/>
    </span>
</div>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/veE8TXHGVJzSa13sZQiD?p=preview
I want to remove background shadow of buttons .but it not works.

```
.image-background{
    background-color: black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

any update ? regarding this image is not display ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ellipsis issue fix:
span is an inline element, you cant able to apply width, so convert it as **inline block**

```
.sign-out span {
    display: inline-blok;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 10%;
}
```

http://run.plnkr.co/7mdpZD3GnPdh2l7O/